# Bind nested json object to Class

Tags: c#, json, api

I´m trying to bind a json object with this structure to ma class recItem:

```
"results": [
    {
        "id": "bjjiga1ee915r25f6vojrrbj5d",
        "name": "25026CE_r4_0-BR-WEB.pdf",
        "default": {
            "Date modified": "20200828114557000",                
            "Size": "18098154"
        }
    }
]
```

I successfully bind all items at root level but how can I bind properties like "Date modified"?

Here are my 2 classes:

```
public class recItem
    {
        public string id { get; set; }            
        public string name { get; set; }    
        [JsonProperty("Date modified")]
        public string dateModified { get; set;}        
        
    }
```

and

```
public class recItemDefault
    {
        [JsonProperty("default")]
        public string dateModified { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64027718/1997232), seems to be very helpful thing for beginners.

Comment: It really solved my problem and all make sense. Thanks @Sinatr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these classes together:

```
public class Rootobject
{
public string id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public Default _default { get; set; }
}


public class Default
{
public string Datemodified { get; set; }
public string Size { get; set; }
}
```